# how to send javascript variable as a php parameter

Tags: php, javascript, parameters

hi i have a javascript function which opens a pop-up window and opens a php file into it but i even want to send a parameter with it but it doesnt work the parameter is sent as a variable name instead of its value
here is my script

```
             <?php 

 if($addflag == 0){
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function mopen(){
var mobj=document.getElementById('dtype').value; //// this variable is shown as a name instead of its value
window.open('quotprin.php?vouchno=' . urlencode($getvouch) . '&dtype=mobj','popUpWindow','height=800,width=950,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
}
</script>
";

echo "<td>";
echo '<font color="red">Print On Letter Head</font>
<input type="checkbox" id="dtype" name="dtype" value="1" checked="checked" />';
echo '<input class="cmdprint" type="button" id="submit" name="print" value="Print" onclick="mopen();"></td>';
echo "<td>";
}
            ?>
```

Comment: give more code, what $getvouch contains? maybe it's bad formatted, have you escaped it? Change this     vouchno=' . $getvouch . '&dtype to this     vouchno=' . urlencode($getvouch) . '&dtype

Comment: sir the problem is with mobj not getvouch but thanks fr ur suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly your original code, but it works. You have too many escape slashes and single or double quotes. It can be too confusing to figure out errors like this.

```
<?php 

$getvouch = isset($_GET['getvouch'])? $_GET['getvouch'] : null;

?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function mopen(){
       var mobj=document.getElementById('dtype').value;
       var url="quotprin.php?vouchno=<?php echo $getvouch; ?>&dtype="+ mobj;
       window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=800,width=950,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
    }
    </script>

    <table><tr><td>
    <font color="red">Print On Letter Head</font>
    <input type="checkbox" id="dtype" name="dtype" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <input class="cmdprint" type="button" id="submit" name="print" value="Print" onclick="mopen();"></td>
    </tr></table>
```

Most important here is to see how the "getvouch" variable is added to the getmobi url.

If you use this url: add-a-javascript-var-and-send-it-with-post.php?getvouch=6

get mobi links to : quotprin.php?vouchno=6&dtype=mobj

If this is not the issue, please explain a little better.

UPDATE.
Now I see the error is you did not escape the mobj variable in the url. try the changes.

Comment: sir the problem is not with with the $getvouch its with the javascript variable mobj

Comment: th mobj is sending its name instead of its value that should be either 0 or 1

Comment: Try the changes in the code. It uses the value of $getvouch and mobj in a url variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:      
<?php 

if($addflag == 0){
$getvouch = urlencode($getvouch);
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function mopen(){
var mobj=document.getElementById('dtype').value; //// this variable is shown as a name     instead of its value
window.open('quotprin.php?vouchno=    {$getvouch}&dtype=mobj','popUpWindow','height=800,width=950,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,    scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
}
</script>
";

echo "<td>";
echo '<font color="red">Print On Letter Head</font>
<input type="checkbox" id="dtype" name="dtype" value="1" checked="checked" />';
echo '<input class="cmdprint" type="button" id="submit" name="print" value="Print"     onclick="mopen();"></td>';
echo "<td>";
}
          ?>
```